# Trouble with wolf texture packs

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image: Example]

I was trying to make a resource pack for minecraft bedrock where only the tame wolf texture is altered, but I ran into a strange issue. Whenever I had a wolf_tame in the pack, in game tame wolves would have that image-but tinted red. I tried swapping out the other wolf files in the pack (normal, collar) but they did not change the outcome. Why did this happen? How can I fix it?

Also, I tried to work and troubleshoot on two devices and several worlds.

Comment: Hi CMK, welcome to Arqade! Do you have the image texture that you used so we can take a look?

Comment: I may have at least one, as the issue persisted with multiple attempts. They included swapping in and out multiple wolf_tame pictures as well as multiple resource packs. To reiterate, I likely have a few pictures or folders I tried, but I am not sure how they would help.

Comment: I found a separate piece on mojang's website from a few years ago, where someone else had the same problem. They seem to have found a solution, but I'm not sure yet: "The wolf_tame must be a .tga file with the collar as the main layer and the body as a second layer to prevent incorrect colouring (will need a specific editor)"